# Laravel 5.1 - Relationship method must return an object of type

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, relationship

My application takes payment from users but sub accounts must not be allowed to see the payment screen.

I have a `Route::group` which checks if the user is allowed to pay through Middleware. The `handle` function look like this

```
    if(!\Auth::user()->isTeacher) 
{
    \Auth::logout();
     return redirect('/login')->withErrors([$error = 'Sorry there was a problem. Please notify your School']);
}        

return $next($request);
```

and the `isTeacher()` function

```
if($this->school_id) {
$teachers = $this->school->find($this->id)->teachers;
$isTeacher = false;
foreach ($teachers as $teacher) {
    if ($teacher->id == \Auth::user()->id) {$teacher = true;}
}

return $isTeacher;
```

}

Finally the School relationship looks like the following

```
return $this->hasOne('App\School', 'id', 'school_id');
```

The error I keep receiving is

> LogicException in Model.php line 2667:
>   Relationship method must return an object of type Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation

In part of the error tree?? it shows this which is from the Middleware

> at Model->__get('isTeacher') in MustBeTeacherToMakePayment.php line 19

which is the if statement on the first line above.

Is anyone able to tell me what I'm doing wrong? This is driving me mad

Comment: What does your `school` relationship look like?

Comment: I believe jedrzej.kurylo is correct, however I also believe you should take a closer look at your `isTeacher()` function.  You are setting variables that you aren't using and you likely want to break out of that loop once `$teacher` becomes true.  Otherwise, it will keep going and probably return false.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instead of calling the **isTeacher()** function you are accessing **isTeacher** attribute. Eloquent sees a method of that name and identifies it as a method that should return relation definition. And then you get the error because relation definition methods should return **Relation** object.

You have to replace

```
if(!\Auth::user()->isTeacher)
```

with

```
if(!\Auth::user()->isTeacher())
```

and the error will be gone.